# What are some common industry practice to overcome FCM "MessageTooBig" limit

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I realize, if I send a large data over FCM

```
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'key={}'.format(constants.FCM_AUTHORIZATION_KEY)}
r = requests.post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', headers=headers,, json=request_data)
```

I would get the following `MessageTooBig` respond

```
{"multicast_id":8254676006929147000,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MessageTooBig"}],"success":0}
```

I notice is caused by the data payload limit described in https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options

> For downstream messaging, GCM provides two types of payload:
>   notification and data. Notification is the more lightweight option,
>   with a 2KB limit and a predefined set of user-visible keys. Data
>   payload lets developers send up to 4KB of custom key/value pairs.
>   Notification messages can contain an optional data payload which is
>   delivered when users click on the notification.

I was wondering, what are some common industry practice, to overcome such limit. The workaround I can think of is

1. Store the large data in server side database.
2. Send only the reference id of the large data in server side database, to client using FCM.
3. Client will retrieve the large data, by communicating to the server using received reference id, via HTTP API call.

I was wondering, is it common industry practice to overcome FCM `MessageTooBig` limit? Any other better alternative way we can try out?

---

### Example of large data over FCM

```
{
  "to": "cHpY6qOkvMM:APA91bHemBImwsqSEo_q_ZO4rxkVwoQ3Jba9xIXKDz7QW2EcDkFkeBT7dF3XtPoSWUsHMybggWRspObQcSQ692j56wYJ1nNY-g5MxW8z4EY91-11log-GBI0RN566Lbt8HlNnxB_MtsV",
  "data": {
    "news_alerts": [
      {
        "code": "BABA",
        "description": "Tired of all the crypto-craziness? Consider these three stocks instead.",
        "sentiment": "negative",
        "title": "Forget Bitcoin: You're Better Off Buying These 3 Stocks",
        "score": "-0.512554",
        "link": "https:\/\/finance.yahoo.com\/news\/forget-bitcoin-apos-better-off-002900487.html?.tsrc=rss",
        "time": 1520641740000
      },
      {
        "code": "BABA",
        "description": "Alibaba, Tencent, JD.com, YY and 58.com, highly rated Chinese internet companies, now have proper bases and buy points. Let's look at the stock charts.",
        "sentiment": "positive",
        "title": "Alibaba, Tencent, JD.com Lead 5 Top Chinese Internets That Just Carved New Buy Points",
        "score": "0.587976",
        "link": "http:\/\/finance.yahoo.com\/r\/bb08a470-7ad4-3339-b5b3-64db04c97fe9\/alibaba-tencent-jd-com-lead-5-top-chinese-internets-that-just-carved-new-buy-points?src=A00220&yptr=yahoo&.tsrc=rss",
        "time": 1520686838000
      },
      {
        "code": "BABA",
        "description": "Cloud computing is transforming the way companies across the world do business. But in China , it is playing an even more transformative role: the country\u2019s biggest consumer-oriented companies are increasingly ...",
        "sentiment": "positive",
        "title": "[$$] Cloud pivots Alibaba, Tencent to business market",
        "score": "0.466677",
        "link": "http:\/\/finance.yahoo.com\/r\/30f3ab86-5c1b-3480-bdde-1e85d23ee890\/d5fb8d22-1228-11e8-940e-08320fc2a277,s01=1.html?ftcamp=traffic\/partner\/feed_headline\/us_yahoo\/auddev&yptr=yahoo&.tsrc=rss",
        "time": 1520740918000
      },
      {
        "code": "BP",
        "description": "BP Stock Has Slumped 8% in 1Q18: What's to Blame?",
        "sentiment": "negative",
        "title": "Why Short Interest in BP Rose",
        "score": "-0.897288",
        "link": "http:\/\/finance.yahoo.com\/r\/8871cdd1-bd33-3313-9216-ca964b34a7b5\/why-short-interest-in-bp-rose?utm_source=yahoo&utm_medium=feed&yptr=yahoo&.tsrc=rss",
        "time": 1520523091000
      },
      {
        "code": "BP",
        "description": "A Look at the Energy Sector's Top Movers This Week",
        "sentiment": "positive",
        "title": "Which Integrated Energy Stocks Are Gaining This Week?",
        "score": "0.557677",
        "link": "http:\/\/finance.yahoo.com\/r\/69b7da55-f061-3c88-b11b-a5e1b587bb8d\/which-integrated-energy-stocks-are-gaining-this-week-2?utm_source=yahoo&utm_medium=feed&yptr=yahoo&.tsrc=rss",
        "time": 1520537652000
      },
      {
        "code": "BP",
        "description": "BP, among other oil majors have reported surprise increases in oil production from aging fields",
        "sentiment": "negative",
        "title": "BP Reports Surprise Production Jump At Mature Fields",
        "score": "-0.432939",
        "link": "https:\/\/finance.yahoo.com\/news\/bp-reports-surprise-production-jump-170000453.html?.tsrc=rss",
        "time": 1520614800000
      },
      {
        "code": "KO",
        "description": "Coca-Cola European Partners, the world\u2019s largest independent Coke bottler, has joined the European war on sugar.  The London-based company, formed in 2016 from the merger of Coca-Cola Enterprises and Coke\u2019s bottling operations in Germany and Spain, has emphasized soft drinks such as Coca Cola Zero Sugar, fruit-flavored ViO Bio, and tea.  It has also introduced mini cans of signature Coca-Cola products.",
        "sentiment": "neutral",
        "title": "[$$] A European Coke Bottler Could Offer Bubbly Returns",
        "score": "0.0",
        "link": "http:\/\/finance.yahoo.com\/r\/a68a7bd5-00e3-3824-a135-b88cba0be129\/a-european-coke-bottler-could-offer-bubbly-returns-1520648871?mod=yahoobarrons&ru=yahoo&yptr=yahoo&.tsrc=rss",
        "time": 1520658060000
      },
      {
        "code": "KO",
        "description": "Which of these consumer-goods leaders is the smarter stock pick?",
        "sentiment": "positive",
        "title": "Better Buy: Altria Group vs. Coca-Cola",
        "score": "0.531775",
        "link": "https:\/\/finance.yahoo.com\/news\/better-buy-altria-group-vs-164800637.html?.tsrc=rss",
        "time": 1520700480000
      },
      {
        "code": "KO",
        "description": "The company will launch its first ever fizzy adult beverage in Japan.",
        "sentiment": "positive",
        "title": "Coca-Cola Dips a Toe Into the Alcohol Market",
        "score": "0.672059",
        "link": "https:\/\/finance.yahoo.com\/news\/coca-cola-dips-toe-alcohol-183000170.html?.tsrc=rss",
        "time": 1520706600000
      },
      {
        "code": "MMM",
        "description": "Analysts\u2019 consensus indicates a target price of $245.90, which implies a return potential of 3.1% over the closing price as of March 7, 2018.  Analysts\u2019 consensus target price for 3M increased from $219.50 to the current price in three months, which indicates bullishness in the stock.  3M reported strong 4Q17 earnings and exceeded analysts\u2019 estimates.",
        "sentiment": "positive",
        "title": "3M: An Update on Analysts\u2019 View",
        "score": "0.731176",
        "link": "http:\/\/finance.yahoo.com\/r\/85233127-bc66-32e3-a5b1-a437689b4aab\/3m-an-update-on-analysts-view?utm_source=yahoo&utm_medium=feed&yptr=yahoo&.tsrc=rss",
        "time": 1520621702000
      },
      {
        "code": "MMM",
        "description": "Warren Buffett once said that \"successful investing takes time.\" Here are three companies to make the wait easier.",
        "sentiment": "neutral",
        "title": "3 Stocks to Buy and Hold for Decades",
        "score": "0.0",
        "link": "https:\/\/finance.yahoo.com\/news\/3-stocks-buy-hold-decades-211100753.html?.tsrc=rss",
        "time": 1520629860000
      },
      {
        "code": "MMM",
        "description": "The market will go down eventually, and these three companies are well prepared for it.",
        "sentiment": "positive",
        "title": "3 Dividend Stocks That Thrive in Both Bull and Bear Markets",
        "score": "0.541903",
        "link": "https:\/\/finance.yahoo.com\/news\/3-dividend-stocks-thrive-both-121500321.html?.tsrc=rss",
        "time": 1520684100000
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like this should be information held on a server and not send through FCM. FCM would just send a general "news alert" message and the app would go get the alerts from the server

Comment: Just speaking from personal experience I have never used GCM/FCM for anything other than a "notification mechanism" meaning I use it to alert a device that there is information to get and the device gets it from a server. This allows for unlimited scalability of data through a http call